# How to convert a javascript map of array into a json object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, jsp

I have a javascript MAP object which is holding key as a string and value as a javascript array, each array is holding set of strings inside it. I want to convert the map of arrays into a json object in javascript.

Here is the code which i tried

function addRole() {

```
 var jsonObjectOfMap={};
    subMenuSelectedIdMap.forEach(function(items,key,subMenuSelectedIdMap){
        jsonObjectOfMap[key]=JSON.stringify(items);
    }); 
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObjectOfMap));
```

I am getting the json object as like this 
**{"1004":"[1005,1006,1023]","1007":"[1008,1053]"}**

But is this json format object is valid and what i have to do if i want it the format as this:
**{"1004":["1005","1006","1023"]","1007":["1008","1053"]}**

Please help me out

Comment: `jsonObjectOfMap[key]=items;` – `JSON.stringify()` doesn't need to be called on each individual object. It's usually only necessary to call it once on the root object – `JSON.stringify(jsonObjectOfMap)`. It already behaves recursively and will stringify any (compatible) values contained within.

Comment: I tried that way but its giving me like this :                                           {"1004":[1005,1006,1023],"1007":[1008,1053]}

Comment: Can you show us the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

If the inner-most values are all numbers and you want them as strings in the end result, you'll have to convert each number individually to a string.

You can do that with another loop over each `items` using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and either calling [`String()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) or [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) for each number:

```
subMenuSelectedIdMap.forEach(function (items, key, subMenuSelectedIdMap){
    jsonObjectOfMap[key] = items.map(function (item) {
        return String(item); // or `return item.toString();`
    });
});
```

---

Optionally, since `String()` only acknowledges one argument (with the other two that `.map()` passes being ignored), the loop over `items` could be shortened to:

```
jsonObjectOfMap[key] = items.map(String);
```